# Kendo UI posts Blank data to Server on fields marked required

Tags: kendo-ui

My little problem is when i hit the Add new record botton on the Kendo Grid it adds a new blank row and when i click the save changes it actually sends a post request to the server even after marking the fields with validation: {required: true}.

Although when i try to update an existing field to a null value the validation kicks off preventing me from saving which is correct.

And how do i get a message displaying "Are You Sure you want to ......" when i hit the Delete botton or Save changes botton? is it auto implemented or do i implement it myself?

Comment: Many questions in one, don't think so? Maybe not all questions can be answered by same person which will refrain from answering hoping that someone with all is going to answer them. Try to separate questions on different posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- required is a UI validation but does not prevent it from being saved on the server. – OnaBai 1 min ago edit
- For getting the popup asking for `delete` confirmation set `editable.confirmation` to `true`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-editable.confirmation)
- There is not *built-in* confirmation for `save`. You need to intercept `save` request and show the confirmation and then do the actual save.